# Attempting to get retURL into variable in Apex trigger, returns null

Tags: apex, trigger, parameters

I have a custom button from a Case to create an Order, and in it I pass the retURL and the saveURL so it can return to the Case once the Order has been created (or save is cancelled). This all works fine.

I would like to get the ID of the Case into a variable in the trigger however, but although I see it in the url when I try and set it in the code it errors saying the parameter is null. What is wrong? How do I get hold of the Case ID?

[image]

```
    string caseID = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL');
```

Comment: As the answer below said there is no apex page to get the URL param from. You should be doing your navigation in the VF page you are using to create the order or in the button itself. How would depend on what exactly happens when they click the button

Comment: If the objective to get parameter from VF, I would like to suggest you might want to try remote object. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_example_simple.htm . I believe that you want to capture from user interface , not data loader.trigger will not work if you want to get value from URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Five bucks says the whole page is null.

```
trigger testTrigger on Account (before insert,before update) {
for(Account a:Trigger.new)
    System.debug(ApexPages.CurrentPage());
}
//13:05:30:008 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|null
```

I don't think a Trigger has the context of the VF page on the DML insert...you'd probably have to query for it or see it in the inserted record. Maybe create a field something along the lines of "SourceId" and parse that in the trigger?

Comment: Ah ok, that explains it :) I was hoping I wouldn't have to create another field to get it into, but seems that is my only option then. Thanks.